# UI Automation using Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, ui-automation

I was using UI automation using windows forms, 
it was working fine , but when i am trying to 
use it with Windows Service , i cannot access 
automation element .Please suggest what i am missing

Comment: There are a lot of considerations in this. 1: a service doesnt use your desktop session so any interaction with your desktop would be out, 2: if you didnt run it as you, it wont have your permissions, mapped drives or whatever, 3: some policies actually prevent any UI elements to services...

Comment: What if I am using interactive service ,how to use it ?

Comment: Per service means for a whole machine, so it's not suited for UI Automation at all. If it's per user, you could write an application that runs in the background, for example in a task scheduler.

Comment: The setting for a [service to interact with the desktop](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#InteractWithDesktop) is misleading. It doesn't do what you expect in modern versions of Windows...